# Counting a collection of models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

Currently I have 3 models: `User`, `Collection` and `Item`.

A `User` has many `Items` through `Collections`
An `Item` has many `Users` through `Collections`

To get a `User`'s collection, I can do `user.items` and display them accordingly.

What I would like to be able to do is aggregate the duplicate items for this list.

Say a `User` adds `Item 1`, then `Item 2` and then another `Item 1`.
The list should be:

```
User

-Item 1 Name - Item 1 Description - Item 1 Category - Qty 2
-Item 2 Name - Item 2 Description - Item 2 Category - Qty 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
item_groups = user.items.group_by(&:id)
@item_counts = item_groups.map {|item_id,items| [items.first, items.size]}
```

In your view:

```
@item_counts.each do |item, size|
  ... item.name, size or whatever you want to print
```

Comment: In the console, I'm getting @item_counts as => {39=>10, 40=>1, 42=>1, 45=>15}.  When I try to do the each do, I'm getting an error on item.name with undefined method 'name' for 39:Fixnum.  Even when I do just size in the each do loop, it returns the full "=> {39=>10, 40=>1, 42=>1, 45=>15}"

Comment: So I would need to display item.name item.type item.count for each combined item.  The SQL would be similar to SELECT name, type, COUNT(*) FROM item GROUP BY id

Comment: I corrected my answer, so that the first element is the actual item not the item id.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

You can group all the items with something like this:

```
user.items.group_by(&:id)
```

...which will get you a hash where the key is an item id and the value is an array of items sharing that id.  You can then further collapse the individual items down to just a count:

```
Hash[user.items.group_by(&:id).map {|k,v| [k, v.size]}]
```

...which will get you a hash where the key is the item id and the value is the number of items with that id.

Comment: I'm able to do this: @user.items.count(:all, :group => 'name') which gives me {"Item 1"=>10, "Item 2"=>1, "Item 3"=>1, "Awesome Beer 4"=>15} but I do not know how to get the count numbers out

Comment: The user.items.group_by(&:item_id) throws an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for :item:Symbol

Comment: It should be `user.items.group_by(&:id)`